# What is the recommended way to run a script when a header file changes

Tags: makefile, gnu

Using GNU make 3.81 (on a Mac)

I have a Python script that generates a linker script file (`flash_map.ld`) from a header file (`partition_map.h`). I want to have the Python script run before the link phase if the header file has changed. The way I have implemented it is not good because the Python script runs every time I run `make` regardless of whether the header file has changed or not. Any suggestions on the "correct" way to do this would be welcome.

Here is how it is right now:

```
all: flashmap $(BIN) show.options

$(BIN): $(LIBS) $(OBJ_FILES) $(LD_FILE)
    @echo "+++ Linking: $@"
...
etc. etc.
...

flashmap: partition_map.h
    @echo ""
    
partition_map.h:
    @echo "++++ Building flash_map.h ++++"
    @$(PYTHON) $(PY_BUILD_LINKER) $(MAP_FILE) $(LINKER_INC_FILE)
```

Regards,
ac

Answer (score 0):

If the rule which recipe calls `$(PYTHON)` builds `flash_map.ld` then the `"++++ Building flash_map.h ++++"` message looks wrong. Let's assume it's a typo.

Your Makefile does not specify the dependencies you depict. Try:

```
flash_map.ld: partition_map.h
    echo "++++ Building flash_map.ld ++++"
    $(PYTHON) $(PY_BUILD_LINKER) $(MAP_FILE) $(LINKER_INC_FILE)
```

This really says that `flash_map.ld` depends on `partition_map.h`, that is, `flash_map.ld` must be built if it does not exist yet or rebuilt if it exists but is older than `partition_map.h`.

Then, you should add the linker script to the list of prerequisites of your linking rule (if it is not already there through a variable):

```
$(BIN): $(LIBS) $(OBJ_FILES) $(LD_FILE) flash_map.ld
```

We cannot comment on the rest (`all`, `flashmap`, `$(BIN)`, `show.options`) because you do not show enough.

Note: you write *"The way I have implemented it is not good because the Python script runs every time I run make regardless of whether the header file has changed or not"*, which is not really possible with the Makefile you show. With what you show your python script should run if and only if `partition_map.h` is required for a make goal and:

1. it does not exist,
2. or you declared it as phony somewhere,
3. or you have another rule for the `partition_map.h` target with some out-of-date, phony or non-existing prerequisites.

Note: it is better to not silence your recipes with `@` if you are still debugging. It prevents you from seeing what's happening. Prefer the `-s` make option if you want to silence the recipes temporarily for one invocation, or use the [`.SILENT` special target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002eSILENT).

Note: the rule you wrote with a python recipe indicates that you probably missed something about the make syntax. As you wrote it it tells make how to build `partition_map.h`, not `flash_map.ld`. You should probably read at least the [Introduction to Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction) part of the GNU make manual to understand the basic structure of make rules:

```
target: prerequisites
    recipe
```